# Calling scanner parameter

Tags: java, parameter-passing, java.util.scanner

Ive created two classes, `Method` and `ActionClass`. in `Mehod` class i created `passingParameters` method  with `Scanner` parameter and in `ActionClass` i created an object and called `passingParameters` method as you see below. but i dont know how to call `Scanner` parameter. it looks like there is difference between calling `Scanner` and other parameters. or im wrong? how can i call Scanner in `ActionClass`?

```
 public class Method{

 public void passingParameters(Scanner input){
    int numInput=input.nextInt();
    System.out.println(numInput);
}
}


 public class ActionClass {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Method newObject=new Method(how to call Scanner? );
    newObject.passingParameters();
}
```

Comment: `Method newObject=new Method(); Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in); newObject.passingParameters(scanner);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could go something like this:

If you want to utilize a Scanner object as you have indicated within your example **main()** method of the **ActionClass** class then you would need to create a Constructor within the Method Class that accepts a Scanner object:

```
package whateverpackage;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Method {

    // Declare a Scanner Object field.
    // This will make the Object global
    // to the entire Class.
    private Scanner scannerInput;

    // Class Constructor
    public Method (Scanner input) {
        this.scannerInput = input;    
    }

    public void passingParameters(){
        System.out.println("Enter a integer value for Parameter: ");
        int numInput = scannerInput.nextInt();
        input.nextLine(); // Empty scanner buffer
        System.out.println("Supplied value was: " + numInput);
    }
}
```

And then your **ActionClass**:

```
package whateverpackage;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class ActionClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Method newObject = new Method(new Scanner(System.in));
        newObject.passingParameters();
    }

}
```

This is particularly handy if you intend to extensively use the Scanner object within the **Method** class for various methods. If however you only intend to sporadically use a Scanner object within the **Method** class then I think the way **@user7** has described to do it in comment may be the way to go in which case a Constructor is not required to carry out the task:

```
package whateverpackage;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Method {

    // Method accepts a Scanner Object as an argument.
    public void passingParameters(Scanner input){
        System.out.println("Enter a integer value for Parameter: ");
        int numInput = input.nextInt();
        input.nextLine(); // Empty scanner buffer
        System.out.println("Supplied value was: " + numInput);
    }
}
```

And then your **ActionClass**:

```
package whateverpackage;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class ActionClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        Method newObject = new Method();
        newObject.passingParameters(scanner);
    }

}
```

The Scanner object can also be declared as a Class field and be global within the **ActionClass** class and then be utilized from any methods within that class without the need to always declare a new instance of Scanner. However the the Object would need to be declared as **static** since the **main()** method is a static method. Any method within the **ActionClass** class using this Scanner object would then also need to be declared as static. Not a big deal in this case but there will come a time when it can be ([here's some interesting reading about **static**](https://www.beyondjava.net/should-you-avoid-or-embrace-static)). To get around this don't use the object within the main() method, use a different method altogether:

```
package whateverpackage;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class ActionClass {

    private Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    // *****************************************
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ActionClass().startApp(args);
    }
    // *****************************************

    private void startApp(String[] args) {
        Method newObject = new Method();
        newObject.passingParameters(scanner);

        justAnotherMethod();
    }

    private void justAnotherMethod () {
        System.out.println("What's your name: ");
        String name = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Your Name is: " + name);
    }

}
```